# Rails: JSON Parsing a URL for later use

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, parsing

I'm trying to accomplish something really easily but I could not solve it to my beginner level in rails. The question is how do you assign a JSON objects attribute to a rails object.. I'm trying to send a request to Google Map's URL with some parameters. Without JSON parsing it works just fine, however when I try to parse it, I receive many errors. The regular JSON response from Google when I query the URL ([http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=40.983204,29.0216549&destination=40.99160908659266,29.02334690093994&sensor=false][1]) is like down below;

```
{
  "routes" : [
    {
      "bounds" : {
        "southwest" : {
          "lat" : 40.98289,
          "lng" : 29.02054
        },
        "northeast" : {
          "lat" : 40.99148,
          "lng" : 29.02388
        }
      },
      "summary" : "Mühürdar Cd",
      "waypoint_order" : [],
      "legs" : [
        {
          "start_location" : {
            "lat" : 40.98322,
            "lng" : 29.02166
          },
          "distance" : {
            "text" : "1.3 km",
            "value" : 1324
          },
```

And goes on.

The code I have to get the "summary" attribute is;

```
@request = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=40.983204,29.0216549&destination=40.99160908659266,29.02334690093994&sensor=false'))
    @result=JSON.parse(@request)["routes"]["summary"]
```

I wanted to ask what would be the proper way for me to get the **summary** attribute from the response?

Comment: From the JSON you've posted, JSON.parse(@request)['routes'] returns an array. So basically, JSON.parse(@request)['routes'][1] should get you the summary.

Comment: Your method is perfectly fine but I have one more problem. I have written `hash['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['duration']` and it gets to a point where I receive a JSON request like `{
  "text" : "6 mins",
  "value" : 373
}`. But I cannot reach neither text or value. What should I add to the end?

Comment: hash['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['duration']['text'] would allow you to access Text and ['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['duration']['value'] the Value. 

Just try 'routes'][0]['legs'][0]['duration'].class to see what type it is and access it accordingly. Cheers.

Comment: @membLoper I've figured it out by myself. But thanks for your valuable comment.

Comment: @membLoper post it as answer, please.

Answer (score 1):

```
hash['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['duration']['text']
```

would allow you to access Text and

```
hash['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['duration']['value']
```

the Value. Just try

```
hash['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['duration'].class
```

to see what type it is and access it accordingly